# What should I use instead of "this week"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request

The company where I work has strange working days; for example, I work for 3 days and another employer works for 5 days.

The company has changed my working days, and I know what the **new** days are. However, I don't know if the new working days will be applied for **this week**, so I want to send an email to my manager to ask her about that.

I tried this.

> Dear Ms XXX.
>
> I want to ask you if my new schedule working will be applied for this week.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terms such as "this week" and "next week" are nebulous terms in English. It's easy for the reader to misunderstand what you mean. In some contexts, "this week" can mean "this *upcoming* week", while in others, "this week" means "the week that we are currently in".

In email correspondence, it's best to explicitly state the dates (or put the dates you are referring to in parentheses), to eliminate the possibility for confusion.

For example, this is how I would recommend wording this:

> I wanted to ask if my new work schedule will be applied for this week (that is, in the work week from August 12th through August 19th), or if my new hours don't start until the following week.

Comment: does the word `schedule` is correct in my case ? and also the word `hours` ?

Comment: I think you can say "my new work schedule" and that would be understood just fine. The phrase "my new working hours" could also be used.

Comment: thank you, and please why you said `wanted` not `want`? thanks in advance

Comment: I would use a past tense ("I wanted to ask if..." or "I was wondering if...") because the _wanting_ or _wondering_ happened first, and then you composed the email. However, it's essentially a toss-up, meaning that you could also use the present tense, and that would be okay as well. That's really a question deserving of its own ELL question; it might get some interesting responses.